# Fatal error: Class 'Error_Processor' not found in .../errors/report.php on line 29

Tags: admin, error, permissions

Every time I try to either create or edit a backend user (i.e. `admin > system > permissions > users`), I get a bunch of errors.

**1. Error_Processor.php not found**

> Unknown error type: [2] include(.../includes/src/Error_Processor.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory Unknown error type:
>   [2] include(): Failed opening '.../includes/src/Error_Processor.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.../includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   Fatal error: Class 'Error_Processor' not found in
>   .../errors/report.php on line 2

**2. Fatal error: Class 'Error_Processor' not found in .../errors/report.php on line 29**

I checked to make sure that my errors folder had both `report.php` and `processor.php`, and checked each file to make sure there weren't any issues. My `processor.php`, which is required once by `report.php` as it should, does contain the `Error_Processor class`.

I tried clearing and recompiling as well as reuploading those scripts from a fresh download of Magento, and nothing's helping. As of now, I can't create or edit any of my backend user accounts, which is really inconvenient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way, I'm on Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 with a few extensions installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround, but I fixed it by renaming `processor.php` to `Error Processor.php` and editing `report.php` (line 27).

> From **require_once 'processor.php'** to **require 'Error Processor.php'**